# Can a Google Apps admin see searches made by accounts?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, google-search, privacy

Is it possible for the owners or admins of a Google Apps account to see the searches made by user accounts when those user accounts are logged in?

My company switched its email system to Google. My address is the same, for example jondoe@example.com, but I must sign through google.com. I log on and check my email from my home PC often.

From home I've often searched for many things using Google. Most are normal searches like 'Where to get pizza', but some are private.

If I am logged on using my email, can my employer see my searches?

Answer (score 3):

By default, I don't see any spot in the Google Apps Admin console where an administrator could see your searches.

Buuut if you're using Google Apps *and* logging into the Chrome browser both at work and at home, an admin *could*

- Reset your password
- Log in to your PC or Chrome as you
- See all of your history in Chrome

Of course, this would not be unnoticed by you, as you would now have a different password. You could also use the [Account Activity Details link](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/45938?hl=en) at the bottom of Gmail to see other sessions you have open.

Answer (score 1):

https://history.google.com/history/ should say "Only you can see your history". No idea if there are some ways around it though, but without access to your account I'd be surprised. Google Search history can be turn off at https://history.google.com/history/settings?hl=en if you want to be extra sure.

Answer (score 0):

@Larry, the other answers have pointed out well that domain administrators cannot view your data. However, to address the elephant in the room, Google can. Google can afford to provide free search services since they make money when they can analyze your searches, determine more thoroughly what kind of person you are, and sell ads targeted to that person. I recommend that any "private" searches should be conducted through a non-profiling search engine designed for privacy (like [duckduckgo.com](https://duckduckgo.com/)).